# Call function from inside a Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, deployment, silent-install, intune

Right now I'm learning the [Powershell App Deployment Toolkit](https://psappdeploytoolkit.com/). PSADT is used in software deployment, to have more control over (silent-)installs, (silent-)uninstalls and repairs of software. To work as expected, it needs a certain directory-structure, which looks like this:

```
Source
│   Deploy-Application.exe
│   Deploy-Application.exe.config
│   Deploy-Application.ps1
│
├───AppDeployToolkit
│       AppDeployToolkitBanner.png
│       AppDeployToolkitConfig.xml
│       AppDeployToolkitExtensions.ps1
│       AppDeployToolkitHelp.ps1
│       AppDeployToolkitLogo.ico
│       AppDeployToolkitMain.cs
│       AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1
│
├───Files
│       installer.msi
│
└───SupportFiles
        info.txt
```

- The `Deploy-Application.ps1` is the place where you put **your own logic**.
- The `AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1` stores the toolkit-functions.
- From inside the `Deploy-Application.ps1` you can call all functions declared in `AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1`.
- With `AppDeployToolkitHelp.ps1` you can overview all usable commands with the synopsis (syntax etc.).

For the purpose of debugging I want to try all commands outside of the `AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1` in a normal powershell. It know that I could just copy out every function and make a new `.ps1`-file, but this seems too tideous. Also I think some functions depend on each other, so I had to copy or read through everything.

Is there a way to import the `AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1`, so I can try out every function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to include in one script the functions from another script, see
[Chapter 10 - Script modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/10-script-modules?view=powershell-7.3) :

> The function needs to be loaded into the *Global* scope. That can be
> accomplished by dot-sourcing the script that contains the function.
> The relative path can be used.
>
> ```
> . .\Get-MrPSVersion.ps1
> ```
>
> The fully qualified path can also be used.
>
> ```
> . C:\Demo\Get-MrPSVersion.ps1
> ```

Comment: For this answer to work with the `AppDeployToolkitMain.ps1` , you either need a powershell with elevated rights or change the `AppDeployToolkitConfig.xml`, where `Toolkit_RequireAdmin` is set to `True` by default.